# Why Mesh Collider is not following 3D object's mesh exactly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

I am new to Unity and having trouble with 3D physics.

I imported a basic 3D "U" bar shape and applied Rigidbody and Mesh Collider. When I drop another object let's say a ball, it does not go into the shape. When I select the shape, I realized a green line between to edges of the U shape which seems like Unity recognizes it as rectangular object.

How I can make Mesh Collider the follow imported mesh's exact shape?

Thank you.

Shape:
[image]
Properties:
[image]
Mesh Collider:
[image]

Comment: post a screenshot

Comment: @vasmos added as requested. Thanks.

Comment: I see mesh renderer, where is mesh collider?

Comment: @vasmos added as well. I tried every cooking options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shape is not convex so if you check the convex option then Unity3d will modify collision shape to be convex. [mesh collider not matching shape](https://answers.unity.com/questions/759520/trouble-with-mesh-collider-help.html)

To fix that, try to uncheck the convex option.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Why a box collider does not collide with this object then? They both have rigidbody compartment assigned? That was the reason I started playing with convex, and when I did check convex than they started the collide.

Comment: From documentation: "GameObjects that have a Rigidbody
 component only support Mesh Colliders that have Convex option enabled: the physics engine can only simulate convex mesh colliders.". To enable collision you need to check convex option, otherwise it won't collide. A typical solution is to add many small simple colliders (e.g. box collider, capsule collider) to cover the whole complex object.